# Devolver todas las filas de una columna hasta que tenga un máximo de carácteres. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Es posible realizar una consulta en MYSQL que te devuelva los valores de una columna hasta que el valor de esta sea inferior o igual a un número de X carácteres? Y en el caso de que esto fuera posible, ¿cómo se hace?

Por ejemplo, tengo una base de datos y una de las columnas (id), pues quiero todos los valores de esa columna hasta que el número de carácteres de esos valores sean igual o menor a 8.

id → aa1 (3).

id → aa2 (6).

id → aa3 (9) -> Este no lo muestra.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo, en realidad tomas el valor de la columna id y vas sumando sus caracteres, por ejemplo el primero son 3 caracteres, el 2do 3 caracteres y ya van 6 caracteres, entonces cuando llegue al 3er ID que seria 9, ya no lo mostraría? Lo que quiero saber es que si es un problema de suma, más que de conteo.

Comment: Si se puede! investiga la instruccion OVER

Comment: Sí, es como dices, @Isanchezo
Pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Después de investigar durante bastante tiempo, he realizado el conteo pero no la suma. Mi consulta es la siguiente: SELECT id, sum(char_length(id)) OVER(PARTITION by id) as 'contador_nombre' FROM usuario;

@gbianchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando más a fondo encontré [una pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044766/mysql-how-to-use-limit-with-select-sum-char-length) a esta, pero en inglés, por si alguien necesita más información pero en resumen la consulta sería:

```
SELECT my_column
FROM
(
 SELECT my_column, ((SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(my_column)) FROM my_table mt2 WHERE mt2.my_key <= mt1.my_key)) as endidx
 FROM my_table mt1
) mt
WHERE endidx > 9000 and endidx <= 9000 + 9000
```

En el caso de que no se tenga una columna única de números consecutivos, la consulta es esta:

```
SELECT my_column
FROM
(
 SELECT my_column, ((SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(my_column)) FROM my_table mt2 )) as endidx
 FROM my_table mt1
) my_table
WHERE endidx > 0 and endidx <= 9000 + 9000 ;
```